# Artisan is trying to use the Ubuntu MySQL database instead of XAMPP's

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I am using Linux for web development for the first time. I am developing an application using Laravel (and XAMPP) and I had no trouble doing so on Windows.

This time, however, whenever I run the `php artisan` command to refresh my database I get an error that Artisan can't connect to the database.

[image: Artisan error]

I realized that he's trying to access Ubuntu's MySQL databse instead of XAMPP's database. That's probably because I am using the global php command instead of running XAMPP's php command (which I used on Windows). I am positive that the `.env` file and the database configuration file point to the correct database.

**Is there a way to make Artisan work with XAMPP's php command? Please remember that I have a very limited Linux knowledge.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should terminate Ubuntu's MySQL server, google how to do this, and then you can start your xampp mysql server with xampp controller.